# Python not able to process the data from Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My problem is that when I run my code it does not execute.

My code reads a excel file and takes the max value from the excel and puts in a array and repeats it 100 times. I used while loop to do it, but the only loads the excel and gets stuck for a long time.

The code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'my_excel.xlsx', sheet_name='record')
print(df)
# Column Describe 
df.columns = [  "DataPoint",
    "Cycle Index",
    "Step Index",
    "Step Type",
    "Time",
    "Cumulative Time".....  ] 
reg_charge = df.loc[df["Step Index"] ==2]
i=2
last=100
x =[]
y =[]
while i < 101:
 yy = reg_charge["Capacity(Ah)"][reg_charge["Cycle Index"] == i]
 xx = reg_charge["Cycle Index"][reg_charge["Cycle Index"] == i]
 xmax=np.max(xx)
 ymax=np.max(yy)
x.append(xmax)
y.append(ymax)
i += 1
```

Any idea how i can make it faster. The Excel is pretty big with 120k rows.

Comment: if the indentation is like this, you never change `i` inside the loop. Check the indentation of the last 3 lines. It's another matter if this is best approach.

Comment: This sounds like you want no loop at all but `reg_charge.groupby("Cycle Index").agg("min", "max")`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You are incrementing "i" outside of the loop which is why it is going into infinity loop. You may need to increment this within the **while** loop.

Comment: Please don't _answer_ using images – you could have just used a `# <--` comment pointing out the line.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to stackoverflow, still learning.